# $A=\{f \mid f:\mathbb{Z}_+ \to \{0,1\}\}$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Consider the set $A=\{f \mid f:\mathbb{Z}_+ \to \{0,1\}\}.$
>   I need to show that it is uncountable.

I was trying to find a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$
or if I can show that there is no injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}_+$ then also it'll work !

Answer (score 4):

> The situation cries out for Cantor's diagonal argument:

Consider any function $s:\mathbb N\to A$ and, for each $n$, call $f_n=s(n)$. Define $f:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ by $f(n)=1-f_n(n)$ for every $n$. Then $f$ is in $A$ but not in $s(\mathbb N)$ (*why?*). Hence $s$ is not a surjection. This proves that $A$ is uncountable.

Comment: i didn't get how you defined $f_n(n)$

Comment: it is a classical cantors diagonal arguement. just have in mind that you have some ordering of them and now you construct a sequence which differs at least in one position from every other

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal he assumed $s$ to be such a surjection and $f_n$ the "counting" of $A$. Then he proves, that one can construct an element out of the scope of $s$, so $s$ is no surjection.

Comment: @AlexR He didn't *assume* that $s$ is a surjection, just a function

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal The number $f_n(n)$ is $0$ or $1$ and defined as the image of $n$ by the function $f_n$.

Comment: @AlexR No a priori surjection here.

Comment: @Did why $f$ is not in $s(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: Because if $f$ was in $s(\mathbb N)$, there would exist $n$ such that $f=s(n)$, but $f(n)\ne f_n(n)$ hence this is impossible.

Comment: Counting was just a failed translation. In fact your proof is actually "Let $s$ be an enumeration of $A$, i.e. $s: \mathbb{N} \to A$ is bijective (esp. surjective), then we can find $f \in A \setminus s(\mathbb{N})$. Therefor $s$ cannot be a surjection, thus no such surjection exists." That's what I meant to explain here...

Comment: @AlexR No, what "you meant to explain" is wrong. The proof nowhere assumes that $s$ is surjective. You insist on seeing a proof by contradiction where there is none.

Comment: It proves, by contradiction (by giving a counterexample), that there exists no _surjection_... Where's your point?

Comment: @AlexR You need to seriously revise your view of what a proof by contradiction and a counterexample are. (Listen, these exchanges have long stopped to be productive (if ever they were) and everything of interest is already on the page, hence allow me to stop here.)

Comment: @Did agreed, but no need to nitpick on terms. The whole point is to understand a proof and it's implications - not what it's called or in how far it is a direct or indirect proof.

Answer (score 1):

Think of binary representation of real numbers in $[0,1]$. 
(You can write every real number in $[0,1]$ as
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}$$
where $a_n\in\{0,1\}$.

This will give you the idea for a surjection from $A$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: how can we write irrationals in this expression?

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal irrationals as well as rationals have a unique $p$-adic representation ($\pi = 3.14159\ldots$ for base $10$)

Comment: @AlexR Unique? Hardly.

Comment: @Did give me a second decadic representation of $\pi$... That is:
$$\pi = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} a_k 10^k$$
with $a_k \in \{0, \ldots, 9\} \quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Did Yes it isn't unique, but at least one exist for every. So we only have surjection as I claimed, not a bijection. At AlexR, for example $0.99999=9\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^n}=1$ does have 2 different representations

Comment: @AlexR Instead of giving orders (which is a sure way to get **no** answer, at least from me), you might try to explain why you think the representation of every real number is unique. If you do so, you are in for a surprise.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I know (and I did not address your answer, only a (wrong) comment on it).

Comment: @Did "modulus Cauchy-sequences" in my "Answer"... Sorry for not being precise. In fact, a surjection suffices anyways.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

By $\mathbb{Z}_+$ you mean $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \ldots\}$? Then
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f(n)2^{-n} \in [0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$$
And for the injection $[0,1] \to A$ chose $$T(x)[n] = \lfloor x\cdot 2^n \text{ mod } 2 \rfloor$$
Then you have $|A| = |[0,1]| = |\mathbb{R}|$ q.e.d.

Comment: The first function is not an injection. The second one does not produce $\{0,1\}$-valued sequences.

Comment: It sure does, modulus Cauchy-sequences. And $\text{mod}$ is to be taken floored, but I don't know the TeX-code for the floor brackets right now.

Comment: "modulus Cauchy-sequences"... ?? Care to explain? // LaTeX: try `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`.

Comment: \lfloor and \floor gives the floor function. How do you know that modulus cauchy sequences doesn't mess up your cardinality? For example if you take the discrete metric only nearly constant sequences are cauchy, so you only have countable many of them

Comment: modulus Cauchy -> $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (f(n)-g(n)) 2^{-n} = 0$$
Is that okay by you?
@DominicMichaelis modulus reduces the cardinality at most (with the euclidean metric), so $|A| \geq |A/\text{cauchy}|$ if I am correct.

Comment: What is "Cauchy" there, I wonder.

Comment: @Did Okay. For $f,g \in A$ define
$$f\sim g :\Leftrightarrow \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (f(n)-g(n)) 2^{-n} = 0$$
Then $A/\sim \to [0,1]$ is injective with the given map. Correct?
Also, my claim was the "inverse" $T$ is injective, as two distinct numbers will yield different maps $Tx$

Comment: @Did it sounds a bit like the Cauchy completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ where real numbers are equivalence classes of cauchy sequence given from the equivalence relation $a_n \sim b_n\iff a_n-b_n$ is a to 0 converging sequence

Comment: @DominicMichaelis yes, that's exactly what I was talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

You can identify $A$ with the power set of $\mathbb Z_+$. What do you know about the cardinality of a power set?

Comment: i know that cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ will me more than continuum, but how do you identify $A$ with power set of $\mathbb{Z}_+$

Comment: The cardinality of $\mathbb Z_+$ is *less than* continuum; it's countable. For any set $X$, the power set of $X$ has greater cardinality than $X$, so in particular the power set of $\mathbb Z_+$ is uncountable. The identification is given by indicator functions.

Comment: so yeah i meant power set of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ has cardinality more than continuum

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g:A\to P(\mathbb{Z_+})$, $ g(f)=\cup_{n:f(n)=1}\{n\}$. This is a bijection between $A$ and $P(\mathbb{Z_+})$, and $|P(\mathbb{Z_+})|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: Isn't $A$ defined to be $2^{\mathbb{Z}_+}$ ?

Comment: No? $A$ is a set of functions.

Comment: How do you define $A^B$ for sets $A,B$ ?

Comment: Maybe what I wrote isn't clear, but I meant $2^S=P(S)$. I'll change it.

Comment: Oh I see, because for me $A^B$ is the set of functions from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: I understand, I'm just not used to that notation.